# Elegant jQuery functions

Tags: jquery, function

I am relatively new to jQuery and I was wondering if the below 
function(s) I did were produced the the most elegant manner possible?
any info is greatly appreciated! thank you

```
 $(function(){
        $('#enter').click(function() {
            $('#enter').fadeOut(80, function () {
            $('#enter').hide( function () { 
            $('#overlay').fadeIn(1500, function () {
            $("#loading").show().delay(500);
            $("#loading").hide( function(){ $("#s5").show(); });
            return false;

        });
    });
    });
        $('#slideTop').animate({ 
            marginTop: '-=230'   
        }, 500, function() {
    });
        $('#slideBottom').animate({ 
            marginBottom: '-=333',
        }, 500, function() {
    });

        });
    });
```

should I have it begin something like this:

```
$(function(){
var cintro = function(){
    $('#box').click(function(){
        $(this).slideUp(
            {duration:1000}//2000,easing:"easeOutBounce"
        );
    setTimeout(function(){
        ('#box').slideUp(
            {duration:1000}//2000
        );}, 6000);
    //$('#box').css({'display': 'block'}).click(function(){$(this).css('display', 'none');
});
    $('#slidenav').slideDown({duration:2000,easing:"easeOutBounce"});
    $('#slider1').data('AnythingSlider').startStop(true);
}
$('#enter').click(cintro);
});
```

Comment: Your question is slightly subjective, define _elegant_, did you mean the smallest/easiest/least-amount-of-code way to do what you want?

Comment: Like using a variable at the end to handle the click event

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
  // cache some selectors that won't ever change
  var enter = $( '#enter' ),
      overlay = $( '#overlay' ),
      loading = $( '#loading' ),
      s5 = $( '#s5' ),
      slideTop = $( '#slideTop' ),
      slideBottom = $( '#slideBottom' );

  enter.click(function() {
    enter.fadeOut(80, function() {
      // i don't think you really need this .hide() but you might...
      enter.hide();
      overlay.fadeIn(1500, function() {
        loading.show().delay(500).hide('slow', function() {
          $("#s5").show();
        })
      });
    });
    return false;
  });

  slideTop.animate({ 
    marginTop: '-=230'   
  }, 500);
  slideBottom.animate({
    marginBottom: '-=333',
  }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a JQuery expert, but there are a few things I would change about this.

If I'm interacting with the same object from the DOM over and over I usually initialize it in a constant rather than select it every time:

```
var $ENTER_BUTTON = null;
...[other elements]...

$(document).ready(function(){
  $ENTER_BUTTON = $('#enter');
  ... [etc] ...
});
```

You also don't need to follow `fadeOut` with `hide` AFAIK.  That's redundant.

If other animations could interfere with the transition use [`stop()`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) appropriately.

Lastly, if any of these transitions can be invoked from other parts of the page, or if you want to make your code a bit more readable I would define a function and reference the function:

```
function enterAnimation(){
  $ENTER_BUTTON.fadeOut(80,function(){
  ... etc
}    

$(document).ready(function(){
  $ENTER_BUTTON = $('#enter');
  ... [etc] ...
  $ENTER_BUTTON.click(enterAnimation);
});
```